# LTPA Timeout Handling In Application Level

Tags: ldap, websphere-7, ltpa

In one of a project, a client asks to extend the LTPA timeout for a project. We can not extend the LTPA timeout in server level. Because the server(WAS 7) has more projects.

So I have googled and in IBM site I got a solution,

it says,

```
LTPA timeout = 120 mins, 
cacheCushionMax = 3 mins (this is the default value)
First Login occurs at = 10:00 AM. (LTPA timeout set to 12:00 PM)
```

**The work items that are submitted after 11:57 AM have an LTPA timeout left that is less than cacheCushionMax, and the LTPA timeout is refreshed.**

I tried with repeated call from the application, for every two minutes to refresh the LTPA token. But the application will be logged out after the time expired. How to rectify this.

Also, I have tried with setup the CacheCushionMax And CacheCusionMin explicitly in WAS.  It does not work.

Please give your suggestions.

[Screenshot for IBM suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0aFY.png)

IBM Suggestion Link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21320747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extend the LTPA token timeout. It is fixed and not based on activity. The information you are referring to applies to only work items that are scheduled when using WPS and BPM and is not applicable to the front end authentication.